# How to test for a react component method been called by another method

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a class that when its initialized it calls another method which calls another method called **pan**. I'm trying to test that the pan method was called. The class is more complicated than that but all I'm trying to test is **pan** was called.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.pan = this.pan.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    initExternals();
  }

  initExternals() {
    .. bla bla
   this.pan();
  }

  pan() {
   console.log('Function was called');
  }

}
```

**Here is my test class**

```
test('component should call initMap', () => {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(WhereWeAreMap.prototype, 'pan');
  const component = mount(<WhereWeAreMap />);
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

I have also tried.
test('component should call initMap', () => {
  const component = mount(<WhereWeAreMap />);
  const spy = jest.spyOn(component.instance(), 'pan');
  wrapper.instance().forceUpdate();
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

What is going wrong with my test as its not able to test the component method **pan** gets called **expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()**. The log shows it gets called but my test shows differently.

> Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called.

Comment: What is your  `test` function supposed to do ? Where is your component rendered ?

Comment: Its supposed to check that the pan method was actually called from inside the MyComponent. MyComponent is rendered as a child of another component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first test method is something that definitely works for me, quickly added it into a test I have running ATM and is fine:

```
  it('adds the correct scroll blocking class to document.body', () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(BlockUI.prototype, 'foo');
    const instance = mount(<BlockUI />).instance();
    // some suggest you need to do this but works without it.
    // instance.forceUpdate();

    const body = instance.document.body;
    expect(body.className).toMatchSnapshot();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

The `BlockUI.prototype.foo` adds a reference to `document.body` to the instance and adds a class to the it that needs to be removed on unmount.

The above setup is fine with:

```
"enzyme": "3.7.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.7.1",
"enzyme-to-json": "3.3.4",
"jest": "23.6.0",
```

I have had difficulties getting this to work previously w/o enzyme or with older versions but now it's fine.

There are exceptions with async stuff that may cause issues - I suggest rather than using a spy, check for the result of the method you want to ensure was called, whatever that is. The lifecycle methods are guaranteed to be called when not using a shallow renderer in enzyme

You are mutating the `pan` method on the instance in the constructor, by saving a local bound copy of it from the prototype - but it should still call through to the prototype and the spy should catch it. I expect you're on older versions of something.

Answer (score -1):

```
   class MyComponent extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.pan = this.pan.bind(this);

      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.initExternals();
      }

      initExternals() {
       this.pan();
      }

      pan() {
       console.log('Function was called');
      }
    }
```

Apply Scope of MyComponent in the componentDidMount method

initExternals should be this.initExternals

My intention with the window object was to say that other scope's could be bound to the function

For example if the function was called with a window scope ie window.initExternals then the this keyword would refer to window

Then ya it would be window.pan

Comment: `window.pan`? o_O you really need to read and understand scope a little better.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff yes you are right, I hadn't taught that one through, you seem like a nice guy, a super duper nice guy, did I spell duper right?